# Distributions with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Number of ways to distribute $80$ balls into $5$ distinguishable bins such that in any bin there will be no more then $24$.

I thought about putting inside the bins $24$, which will give me $120$ balls, but I only have $80$, so I need to take back $40$. Is the next equation equivalent  to the solution of the next formula?

$$ x_{1} +x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5} = 40 $$

and if so, why? I can't seem to understand that type of solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion principle gives $$\sum_{r=0}^{5}(-1)^r\binom{5}{r}\binom{84-25r}{4}\mathbf{1}_{\{84-25r\geq 0\}}=116371$$ A slightly more efficient formula can be obtained by counting the number of ways of taking away total $40$ balls from $5$ bins, each of which is initially filled up with $24$ balls: $$\sum_{r=0}^{5}(-1)^r\binom{5}{r}\binom{44-25r}{4}\mathbf{1}_{\{44-25r\geq 0\}}=\binom{44}{4}-5\binom{19}{4}=116371$$

Comment: @SangchulLee can you clarify how did you come up with this term, and what is this notation:$1_{\{84-25r\ge 0\}}$

Answer (score 1):

So you are partitioning 80 into 5 parts and each part $\le 24$
into distinguishable bins; the usual nomenclature is to call
this weak compositions of 80 into 5 parts with parts $\le 24$.
To simplify the nomenclature distribute $n=80+5=85$ balls
into bins with each part in the range $1\ldots 25$, so this
is the number of compositions of 85 in 5 parts with no parts larger than $25$.
Assume the generating function of putting balls into a bin
is $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{25} x^i$, then the generating function
for 5 bins in a row is
$$g(x)^5=x^5+5x^6+15x^7+35x^8+70x^9+126x^{10}+\cdots+124770x^{84}+116371x^{85}+\cdots$$, because multiplying the five $g$
with the distributive property of multiplication adds the exponents.
The answer is the factor in front of $x^{85}$, which is $[x^{85}]g(x)^5=116371$